# Set initial value in ModelChoiceField at setup

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to figure out how to set the initial value of a ModelChoiceField when it's created (not on form creation). Below is a very simplified example of what I have now, and I'd like to set a default for **State** and **Country** when they render.

I thought this could be done in the `SetBillingInfo` class in `Forms.py`, but can't get it to work. Say I want to default to **California** for state and **United States** for country. Is there a way to set this?

**FORMS.PY**

```
class SetBillingInfo(forms.Form):

    state = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=States.objects.all().order_by('group_order','name'),
        to_field_name='name',
        label = '',
        required=False
    )

    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Country.objects.all().order_by('group_order','name'),
        to_field_name='name',
        label = '',
        required=True
    )
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
billinginfo = SetBillingInfo(initial=request.GET)
return render(request, 'index.html',{'billinginfo': billinginfo})
```

**INDEX.HTML (this is not exactly correct but you get the idea)**

```
            {% for field in billinginfo %}
                <select class="FormRow">
                        {{ field }}
                </select>

            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

in **forms.py**

```
default_state=States.objects.get(name='California')

state = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=States.objects.all().order_by('group_order','name'),
        to_field_name='name',
        label = '',
        initial=default_state,
        required=False
    )
```